# Update column of different table based on manipulated result of another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table1 like below having more than 400k records.Below I'm just showing example, how it look likes. I want to write some query to iterate through each row and find its corresponding date; if all dates are present for the account ID , then I have to update another table2 "Yes". And, if any one of the date is null (for any account ID) then I have to update table2 flag as "No".

This is my source table1.

Table1

```
 Account ID | Date
----------- |------------
   1        | 12-03-2015
   1        | 11-03-2015
   1        | 11-04-2015
   1        | 01-03-2015
   2        | 06-03-2015
   2        | 11-03-2015
   2        | Null
   2        | 01-03-2015
```

This is how the table2 result will look like (after query execution)

Table2

```
Account ID | Flag
-----------|------
1          | Yes
2          | No
```

2ndly, if after few days, Date of Account ID is changed from Null to an actual date (say 07-07-2015), then Table2 "Account ID 2" value should change from "No" to "Yes". So after few days the Table2 should look like this

```
Account ID | Flag
-----------|------
1          | Yes
2          | Yes
```

Hope I have explained it correctly.I'm thinking to use cursor, however, I'm not sure how to use this and will cursor really solve this problem? Is there any other ways to achieve this? Checked on net, however, not able to get suitable solution, please help?

Comment: Can Table 2 be just a view on table 1 with simple case statement? Then you don't need to update, it will be done automatically

Comment: Table2 is a different table. Tried one answer here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8fbf/1 . Showing error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your mindset from looking at every row. This is a very simple set based solution. You should also use better names than DATE and Flag but whatever, this will return the desired output you are after.

```
select AccountID
    , case MIN(case when [Date] is null then '' else [DATE] end) when '' then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Flag
from Table1
group by AccountID
```

Comment: I need to update table2, how to update this. Tried here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8fbf/1) , however, getting error.

Comment: Are you really used postgre? You have this question tagged with sql server but your sqlfiddle is using postgre. Copying and pasting you code into sql server works just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry. I need it for SQL server. Will try and update. Thanks.

Comment: Then the code you posted should work fine. Just change your fiddle to use sql server and it works perfectly fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8fbf/1